# If {there is no image} OR {if there is no expert} then use a certain image

Tags: playa, conditionals, channel-images

Here in this code I am finding a feed expert and then producing his avatar. Conditions are needed to control the conditions of this avatar output. So this is what must happen:

- firstly if there is a expert in the channel entry then use his avatar
  BUT (here is where the if statement comes in)
- if you choose an expert *who does not have an image in the images channel* then show this default image OR if you DO NOT choose an expert then also show the default image.

How do I do this? See code:

```
    {if "{feed_expert:total_children}" > 0}
    {exp:playa:children field="feed_expert" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-7">
    <div class="feed-expert">
    {exp:channel_images:images entry_id="{entry_id}" field_id="185" limit="1"}
    {if image:no_images}<img src="/httpdocs/static/img/sihlouette.jpg" class="img-responsive">{/if}
<img src="{image:url}" class="img-responsive"/>
{/exp:channel_images:images}                                                </div>
 </div>  
{/exp:playa:children}  
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need an else statement

```
{if "{feed_expert:total_children}" > 0} {!-- If expert is selected --}
   {exp:playa:children field="feed_expert" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-7">
        <div class="feed-expert">
        {exp:channel_images:images entry_id="{entry_id}" field_id="185" limit="1"}
           {if image:no_images} {!-- Output default image --}
              <img src="/httpdocs/static/img/sihlouette.jpg" class="img-responsive">
           {/if}
           <img src="{image:url}" class="img-responsive"/>
        {/exp:channel_images:images}
        </div>
     </div>  
   {/exp:playa:children}  
{if:else} {!-- If no experts are selected output default image--}
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-7">
     <div class="feed-expert">
        <img src="/httpdocs/static/img/sihlouette.jpg" class="img-responsive">
     </div>
   </div>
{/if}
```

Comment: This worked, but the images stopped displaying on the 3rd entry, seems like a limit issue. Thanks